# What is the difference between Content-Type...charset=X and Content-Encoding=X?

Tags: http, encoding, utf-8, http-headers

Is there any effective difference between

```
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Optional parameter `charset` makes sense only for text-based content (`Content-Types` like `text/plain`, `text/html`, and such). Not all messages are text.

`Content-Encoding` means that the whole body has been encoded in some way (usually compressed). Typical values for this header are `gzip` and `deflate`. The recipient of this message should decode (e.g. ungzip) the body to get the original message.

I'm not even sure if `UTF-8` makes any sense as a value for the `Content-Encoding`.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't make any logical sense as `Content-Encoding`, as you say. Only general-purpose transformation make sense here (and usually it is restricted to compression formats).

Comment: Is it OK to say Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary (because it's compressed) and Content-Encoding: UTF-8 (for what you get when it's uncompressed)?

Comment: Seamus: no. C-T-E doesn't exist in HTTP, and UTF-8 isn't a meaningful Content-Encoding.

Answer (score 12):

According to *RFC 7231 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content*, the [`Content-Encoding` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.2) contains a list of *content coding* values. Quoting [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.1):

> Content coding values indicate an encoding transformation that has
> been or can be applied to a representation.  Content codings are
> primarily used to allow a representation to be compressed or
> otherwise usefully transformed without losing the identity of its
> underlying media type and without loss of information.  Frequently,
> the representation is stored in coded form, transmitted directly, and
> only decoded by the final recipient.

> ```
> content-coding = token
> ```

> All content-coding values are case-insensitive and ought to be
> registered within the "HTTP Content Coding Registry", as defined in
> Section 8.4.  They are used in the Accept-Encoding (Section 5.3.4)
> and Content-Encoding (Section 3.1.2.2) header fields.

Section 8.4 says:

> The "HTTP Content Coding Registry" defines the namespace for content
> coding names (Section 4.2 of [RFC7230]).  The content coding registry
> is maintained at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters.

The registry currently lists:

```
br           Brotli Compressed Data Format                [RFC7932]     
compress     UNIX "compress" data format                  [RFC7230] Section 4.2.1
deflate      "deflate" compressed data ([RFC1951])        [RFC7230] Section 4.2.2
             inside the "zlib" data format ([RFC1950])
exi          W3C Efficient XML Interchange
gzip         GZIP file format [RFC1952]                   [RFC7230] Section 4.2.3
identity     Reserved (synonym for "no encoding" in       [RFC7231] Section 5.3.4
             Accept-Encoding)
pack200-gzip Network Transfer Format for Java Archives
x-compress   Deprecated (alias for compress)              [RFC7230] Section 4.2.1
x-gzip       Deprecated (alias for gzip)                  [RFC7230] Section 4.2.3
```

UTF-8 is a [*character encoding scheme*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6365#page-8) that can't be used to transform arbitrary binary data losslessly (at least not in a way that would make any sense). It's simply wrong to set `Content-Encoding` to `UTF-8`. User agents might simply ignore the unknown value or discard the message and report an error. The correct place to set the *character encoding scheme* is the [`Content-Type` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5).

Comment: Actually, a user agent ignoring an unknown value for Content-Encoding would be seriously buggy.

Comment: @JulianReschke Ignoring unknown Content-Encoding values seems to be [widespread practice](http://noxxi.de/research/unusual-http-content-encoding.html).

Comment: well, the fact that bugs exists do not make them less serious.

Comment: Very useful answer. Thanks