# Retrieve the content of a web page

Tags: java, string

I'd like to fetch a webpage and save the content as a string? Is there a library to do that? I want to use the string for some a program I am building. It's for websites, that don't necessarily provide rss feed.

Comment: [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/)

Comment: I can't possibly you believe you didn't find one. I don't believed you even began to search. [First Google result of 'java fetch webpage'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)

Comment: @user2516730 you should flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: Probably HtmlUnit might help you.

Comment: @antiearth thanks, maybe the keyword i used to search was not accurate to the problem I was having.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It would be nice if you provide an example. Really.

Comment: @yannishristofakis if you access to the links I've provided, there are lot of examples to accomplish the task asked by OP. Really.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ok,thnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you need this

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = null; // con.getContentEncoding(); *** WRONG: should use "con.getContentType()" instead but it returns something like "text/html; charset=UTF-8" so this value must be parsed to extract the actual encoding
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(body);
```

Comment: Be careful, `con.getContentType()` should be used instead of `con.getContentEncoding()`, but it returns something like `"text/html; charset=UTF-8"` so this value must be parsed in order to extract the actual encoding (I've added a comment on the code above to reflect this)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938007/what-is-the-difference-between-content-type-charset-x-and-content-encoding-x concerning my previous comment (`con.getContentEncoding()` is used for things like "gzip", "compress", ... not encoding)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest JSoup ?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.google.com").get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/index.html)

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.gr");
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) { 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
           System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
        response.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HttpClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Do you know if this is slower or faster than the accepted answer?

Comment: @dentex I don't know.

Comment: @dentex I don't think you gain to much in performance. Don't forget you want to access a remote resource,so it's not up to you how fast your result will come,if speed is what concerns you. `Apache HttpComponents` gives you much more functionality like asynchronous calls. It's up to you.