# Difference between content-type and content-encoding?

Tags: http, encoding, http-headers, mitmproxy

I know the title is basically a duplicate of [What is the difference between Content-Type...charset=X and Content-Encoding=X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938007/what-is-the-difference-between-content-type-charset-x-and-content-encoding-x), but please let me elaborate, since in my opinion the answer(s) do(es) not entirely cover the question.

I am using charset-normalizer to decode pages with my proxy.
However when using charset-normalizer, it crashes on all sorts of errors etc. Upon digging a bit deeper I noticed the content-encoding and content-type differed.

The `content-type` would be `"text/html; charset=UTF-8"` and the `content-encoding` would be `gzip` in the *request* for example.

I then read the documentation of *mitmproxy* again and noticed the following when using `.content` property:

> Accessing this attribute may raise a `ValueError` when the HTTP **content-encoding** is invalid.

(source: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/8af4055e3b1e4587430b7bf7a666424f66e03560/mitmproxy/http.py#L318)

whereas `.raw_content` is:

> The raw **(potentially compressed)** HTTP message body.

(source https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/8af4055e3b1e4587430b7bf7a666424f66e03560/mitmproxy/http.py#L303)

So it's "decoding" (I assume it's decoding) the GZIP here?

When using `.content` to retrieve the content of the webpage and pass this to charset-normalizer, everything works as it should, whereas if I use `.raw_content` it starts to throw errors such as `error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name`.

***My question (which in my opinion wasn't answered well enough in the linked post)***

What's the difference between these 2 and should I first "unzip" the requested file (which happens when I use `.content`  prior to passing it to charset-normalizer, or am I misunderstanding what `content-type` and `content-encoding` do?

Comment: See [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding): "*Note that the original media/content type is specified in the Content-Type header, and that the Content-Encoding applies to the representation, or "coded form", of the data. If the original media is encoded in some way (e.g. a zip file) then this information would not be included in the Content-Encoding header.*" So yes, if the text is compressed, you will have to decompress it first before you can then process the charset data

Comment: Also be aware that [Transfer-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) exists, too